# Inject one service (factory) into another, both of which are async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-scope

I should do the following:

- query an API for a large dataset of names, probably via a service/factory, using `$q` (async)
- have another service (also async) which should only return elements of the above factory if they match a certain string (search field). The aim is to narrow the values so there are reasonably low number of values so my select box can handle it.

  - my controller should call the second service, obtain these values and assign to `$scope` property to be further used by the select box (directive).

I think I should inject only the second (narrowed values) service/factory in my controller. The first factory (large dataset) should be injected as a dependency in the second service where the comparison would occur and therefore narrowed resultset is created.

However, when I inject the factory with the large dataset, I'm not sure how am I supposed to assign its data to a variable/object so I can further use it within the second factory.
If I `console.log` it, it's displayed as a promise

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
```

instead of returning the dataset.

The first mentioned factory:

```
    .factory('MedicationDisplayNamesFactory', function MedicationDisplayNamesFactory($http, $q){

        return {
            getDisplayNames: function(){
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/spellingsuggestions?name=ambien',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
            }

        };

        return MedicationDisplayNamesFactory;

    })
```

The second:

```
    .factory('MedicationMatchingNamesFactory', 
                ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', 'MedicationDisplayNamesFactory', 
                    function MedicationMatchingNamesFactory($http, $q, $timeout, MedicationDisplayNamesFactory){

        return {
            getMatchingNames: function(){
                var foo = MedicationDisplayNamesFactory.getDisplayNames().then(
                            function(response){
                                var bar = response.data.suggestionGroup.suggestionList.suggestion;
                            }
                        );

                console.log(foo);

                return foo;

            }
        };   


        return MedicationMatchingNamesFactory;

    }])
```

In controller, I should be able to call:

```
$scope.myData = MedicationMatchingNamesFactory.getMatchingNames();
```

Something like this.

Comment: show your code so we can help you. You have to call the `.then(successCallback(yourData) {...})` function of the promise. Once the promise is resolved, the successCallback will be called with the data as argument. You can chain promises to achieve what you would like.

Comment: @apairet I updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't accept the answer provided as i haven't tested it - I simplified the two factories and finally went with using `sessionStorage` to persist the resultset of one factory in memory, while narrowing that value in the second.

This may be useful to someone else so I'm putting it here:

```
// save the large dataset to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.allNames = angular.toJson(allNames);

// read saved dataset and assign it to a variable
var allNames = angular.fromJson( sessionStorage.allNames );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a callback function for HTTP response and passed it as parameter to getMatchingNames:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="name in myData">
                    {{name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MedicationMatchingNamesFactory', function($scope, MedicationMatchingNamesFactory) {
                var setMyData = function(myData) {
                    $scope.myData = myData;
                }
                
                MedicationMatchingNamesFactory.getMatchingNames(setMyData);
            }]).factory('MedicationDisplayNamesFactory', function MedicationDisplayNamesFactory($http, $q){

                return {
                    getDisplayNames: function(){
                        return $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/spellingsuggestions?name=ambien',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-type': 'application/json'
                            }
                        });
                    }

                };

                return MedicationDisplayNamesFactory;

            }).factory('MedicationMatchingNamesFactory', 
                       ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', 'MedicationDisplayNamesFactory', 
                        function MedicationMatchingNamesFactory($http, $q, $timeout, MedicationDisplayNamesFactory){
                            return {
                                getMatchingNames: function(callback){
                                    MedicationDisplayNamesFactory.getDisplayNames().then(function(response){
                                        var data = response.data.suggestionGroup.suggestionList.suggestion;
                                        callback(data);
                                    });
                                }
                            };   
                        }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I've already sorted it out somehow. but please, take a look at this question, it deals with the issue which is a part of the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169188/in-my-service-factory-i-lookup-up-a-large-dataset-i-want-to-persist-it-and-che